# "I did whatever it took"

Tags: grammar

A scene from **[Suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suits_(American_TV_series))** Season 4 E13 with the following conversation:

> Daniel Hardman: This is about figuring out who would do whatever it
> takes.
> Harvey Spector: I did whatever it *took*.
>
> ....
> ....
>
> Harvey Spector: Well, what the hell did Louis do to get in line?
> Daniel Hardman: He did whatever it took

Why is it "took" but not "take"?

Answer (score 2):

In both responses "took" is appropriate since the taking occurred in the past.

Comment: Shouldn't *did* be with *base form*?

Comment: @CuppaCoffee Why would you think that? Hint: Consider what category "whatever it took" belongs in.